# Proving Proposition 8.2.6 from Terence Tao's Analysis I

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am currently studying Terence Tao's *Analysis I* and am currently stuck on trying to prove one of the propositions concerning absolutely convergent series over arbitrary sets, which he left as an exercise problem. The question is this:

> Let $X$ be an arbitrary set (possibly uncountable), and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions such that the series $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ and $\sum_{x \in X} g(x)$ are both absolutely convergent.
>
> (a) The series $\sum_{x \in X} ( f(x) + g(x) )$ is absolutely convergent, and $$\sum_{x \in X} (f(x) + g(x)) = \sum_{x \in X} f(x) + \sum_{x \in X} g(x).$$

Of course, there are more components to this proposition, but I can't solve the first one. I understand how to solve the problem in the case where $X$ is finite or countable; for reference, he defines the value of a series over an uncountable set as

> We can define the value of $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ for any absolutely convergent series on an uncountable set $X$ by the formula $$\sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \sum_{x \in X: f(x) \ne 0} f(x),$$ since we have replaced a sum on an uncountable set $X$ by a sum on the countable set $\{x \in X: f(x) \ne 0\}$.

He defines absolute convergence as

> Let $X$ be a set, and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. We say that the series $$\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$$ is absolutely convergent iff $$\sup\bigg\{\sum_{x \in A} \lvert f(x) \rvert: A \subset X, A \text{ finite}\bigg\} < \infty.$$

I managed to prove the first part of the problem i.e. that the series $\sum_{x \in X} (f(x) + g(x))$ is absolutely convergent, as follows:

Let $\sup\{ \sum_{x \in A} f(x): A \subset X, A \text{ finite}\} = M$ and let $\sup\{ \sum_{x \in A} g(x): A \subset X, A \text{ finite}\} = N$. Since $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ and $\sum_{x \in X} g(x)$ are both absolutely convergent, we know that $M, N < \infty$. Thus for any finite subset $A \subset X$, we have $$\sum_{x \in A} \lvert f(x) + g(x) \rvert \leq \sum_{x \in A} \lvert f(x) \rvert + \sum_{x \in A} \lvert g(x) \rvert \leq M + N,$$ so $\sup\{\sum_{x \in A} \lvert f(x) + g(x) \rvert: A \subset X, A \text{ finite}\} \leq M + N$. In particular, $\sum_{x \in X} ( f(x) + g(x) )$ is absolutely convergent.

However, I'm not sure how to prove the second part of the claim; Tao indicates that it requires the axiom of choice when $X$ is uncountable, but I'm still unsure how to approach this problem. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = \{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}, B = \{x\in X: g(x)\neq 0\}, C = \{x\in X: f(x)+g(x) \neq 0\}$ - countable sets.

$$\sum_{x\in X} (f(x)+g(x)) := \sum_{x\in C} (f(x)+g(x)) =\\\sum_{x\in C}(f(x)+g(x))+\sum_{x\in (A\cup B)\setminus C}(f(x)+g(x)) =  \sum_{x\in A\cup B}(f(x)+g(x)) $$ but also
$$\sum_{x\in X} f(x) := \sum_{x\in A} f(x) = \sum_{x\in A\cup B} f(x) $$ and similarly for $g$, so we reduced the problem to the countable case.

Comment: I guess I just didn't realize that for two sets $X$ and $Y$, we have $\sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \sum_{y \in Y} f(y)$ when $\{x \in X: f(x) \ne 0\} = \{y \in Y: f(y) \ne 0\}$, regardless of whether $X = Y$ or not. Thanks!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $C\subset A\cup B $ and $f(x)+g(x) = 0$ on $(A\cup B)\setminus C$. Both of those sums are over countable sets and absolutely convergent, in particular they are convergent regardless of the ordering of the elements to one unique element of $R.

Comment: @EmorySun that's generally not true.

Comment: @EmorySun is it more clear now? Do you need further explanation why you can sum series by blocks?

Comment: Wait, why is it not generally true? If $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ is absolutely convergent, doesn't it follow from definition that $\sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \sum_{x \in X: f(x) \ne 0} f(x)$ is absolutely convergent? Thus, if $Z = \{y \in Y: f(y) \ne 0\} = \{x \in X: f(x) \ne 0\}$, we have $\sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \sum_{x \in X: f(x) \ne 0} f(x) = \sum_{z \in Z} f(z) = \sum_{y \in Y} f(y)$, where the last equality holds by definition?

Comment: Of course, I bring this up because this property should be able to be proven (using the definitions, of course) without the fact that if $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ is absolutely convergent, $X_1 \cup X_2 = X$, and $X_1 \cap X_2 = \varnothing$, then $\sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \sum_{x \in X_1} f(x) + \sum_{x \in X_2} f(x)$. This property is placed after the one mentioned in the question, so proving $\sum_{x \in X} (f(x) + g(x)) = \sum_{x \in X} f(x) + \sum_{x \in X} g(x)$ shouldn't require its use.

Comment: @EmorySun Oh, yes, my mistake, for some reason I thought you meant that the sets are equal regardless of choice $X$ and $Y$. It's not so much from definition (since it's for uncountable sets). I'd rather say it's a property of infinite (countable) sums. We can order the first set arbitrarily, and then the second set such that we place the zero's in between the non-zero elements. Then we have a subsequence of partial sums of the second sum equal to partial sums of the first sum, so sums must be equal.

Comment: Tao hasn't yet introduced any propositions that allow you to equate the following sums over countable sets. $$\\\sum_{x\in C}(f(x)+g(x))+\sum_{x\in (A\cup B)\setminus C}(f(x)+g(x)) =  \sum_{x\in A\cup B}(f(x)+g(x)) $$  
I think this is why Tao mentions the need to use the axiom of choice. Honestly, it seems like it would have been better had Tao covered such countable theorems first rather than doing both countable and uncountable at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need AOC for this one. He's probably referring to part(d).
Denote $A := \{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}, B := \{x\in X: g(x)\neq 0\}, C := \{x\in X: f(x)+g(x) \neq 0\}$. We know they are all at most countable. Here's my proof for the case when **both $A,B$ are countably infinite**.

By Tao's definition 8.2.5, for the absolutely convergent series on an uncountable set $X$: $$ \sum_{x \in X} f(x) = \sum_{x \in X: f(x) \neq 0}f(x) $$
It's easy to verify the equality also holds for countable and finite sets, and we will use this conclusion later.

We want: $$ \sum_{x \in C} (f(x) + g(x)) = \sum_{x \in A} f(x) + \sum_{x \in B} g(x) $$

Observe $C \subset A \cup B $, thus $$\sum_{x \in C} (f(x) + g(x)) = \sum_{x \in A \cup B} (f(x) + g(x)) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(s(n))+g(s(n))$$, where $s: N \to A \cup B$ is a bijection. Now we have to break it down to partial sum $S_N$.

Let $S_N$ be the partial sum and $S_N := \sum_{n=0}^{N} f(s(n)) + g(s(n)) $. Since it's finite, we can split it by Lemma 7.1.4(c).
$$ S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N} f(s(n)) + \sum_{n=0}^{N} g(s(n))$$

Notice the two series are absolutely convergent:
$$\sum_{x \in A} f(x) = \sum_{x \in A \cup B} f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(s(n)) = L_1$$
$$\sum_{x \in B} g(x) = \sum_{x \in A \cup B} g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g(s(n)) = L_2$$

where $L_1,L_2$ are some real numbers.

Thus, $\exists N_1 $ such that $\forall n\geq N_1, \sum_{n=0}^{N} f(s(n))$ is $\epsilon / 2$-close to L1. Similarly for the second term, $\exists N_2 $ such that $\forall n\geq N_1, \sum_{n=0}^{N} f(s(n))$ is $\epsilon / 2$-close to L2. Let $N_0 = max(N_1,N_2)$, then $\forall n \geq N_0, S_N$ is $\epsilon$-close to $L_1+L_2$. Which means $\sum_{x \in C} (f(x) + g(x))$ converges to $L_1+L_2$.

Answer (score 0):

One must first prove Proposition $8.2.6(c)$ in the book which states that if $X = X_{1}\cup X_{2}$ for disjoint sets $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ then $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$ is absolutely convergent if and only if $\sum_{x\in X_{1}}f(x)$ and $\sum_{x\in X_{2}}f(x)$ are both absolutely convergent and
$$\sum_{x\in X}f(x) = \sum_{x\in X_{1}}f(x)+\sum_{x\in X_{2}}f(x).$$

Let $$A = \{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\},$$ $$B = \{x\in X: g(x)\neq 0\},$$ $$C = \{x\in X: f(x)+g(x)\neq 0\},$$ $$D = \{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0,\:g(x)\neq 0,\:f(x)+g(x) = 0\}.$$

We note that $A\cup B = C\cup D$, $C\cap D = \varnothing$ and all sets are at most countable. Therefore, using the result written above we have

$$\sum_{x\in A\cup B}(f(x)+g(x)) = \sum_{x\in C}(f(x)+g(x))+\underbrace{\sum_{x\in D}(f(x)+g(x))}_{ = 0}.$$

Letting $h$ be any bijection from $N$ to $A\cup B$ where $N$ is either $\mathbb{N}$ or $\{k\in \mathbb{N}: 1\leq k\leq n\}$ for some $n$ we have

$$\sum_{x\in A\cup B}(f(x)+g(x)) = \sum_{n\in N}(f(h(n))+g(h(n))) = \sum_{n\in N}f(h(n))+\sum_{n\in N}g(h(n)) = \sum_{x\in A\cup B}f(x)+\sum_{x\in A\cup B}g(x)$$

where the second equality is obtained using the property for finite or countable sums. Again using Proposition $8.2.6(c)$ (stated above) we get

$$\sum_{x\in A\cup B}f(x) = \sum_{x\in A}f(x)+\underbrace{\sum_{x\in A\cup B-A}f(x)}_{ = 0}$$

and similarly $\sum_{x\in A\cup B}g(x) = \sum_{x\in B}g(x)$. Therefore, we have proved that

$$\sum_{x\in C}(f(x)+g(x)) = \sum_{x\in A}f(x)+\sum_{x\in B}g(x)$$

which is the desired result.